# Android Pay: BadParcelableExcaption for com.google.android.gms.wallet.shared.BuyFlowConfig

Tags: android, stripe-payments, android-pay

I'm having this weird problem and I couldn't find any help online.

I have my `BaseActivity` where I have the following code:

```
@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options) {
    intent.putExtra(Constants.ARG_FROM_ACTIVITY, getClass().getName());
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode, options);
}
```

Now, I am trying to integrate Android Pay in my `PaymentActivity` as follows:

```
private void showWallet() {
        WalletFragmentStyle walletFragmentStyle = new WalletFragmentStyle()
                .setBuyButtonText(WalletFragmentStyle.BuyButtonText.BUY_WITH)
                .setBuyButtonAppearance(WalletFragmentStyle.BuyButtonAppearance.ANDROID_PAY_LIGHT)
                .setBuyButtonWidth(WalletFragmentStyle.Dimension.MATCH_PARENT);

        WalletFragmentOptions walletFragmentOptions = WalletFragmentOptions.newBuilder()
                .setEnvironment(WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST)
                .setFragmentStyle(walletFragmentStyle)
                .setTheme(WalletConstants.THEME_LIGHT)
                .setMode(WalletFragmentMode.BUY_BUTTON)
                .build();

        SupportWalletFragment supportWalletFragment = SupportWalletFragment.newInstance(walletFragmentOptions);

        MaskedWalletRequest maskedWalletRequest = MaskedWalletRequest.newBuilder()
                .setPaymentMethodTokenizationParameters(PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters.newBuilder()
                        .setPaymentMethodTokenizationType(PaymentMethodTokenizationType.PAYMENT_GATEWAY)
                        .addParameter("gateway", "stripe")
                        .addParameter("stripe:publishableKey", "<my-key>")
                        .addParameter("stripe:version", Stripe.VERSION)
                        .build())
                .setShippingAddressRequired(false)
                .setEstimatedTotalPrice("1.00")
                .setCurrencyCode("USD")
                .build();

        WalletFragmentInitParams initParams = WalletFragmentInitParams.newBuilder()
                .setMaskedWalletRequest(maskedWalletRequest)
                .setMaskedWalletRequestCode(MASKED_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE)
                .build();

        supportWalletFragment.initialize(initParams);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, supportWalletFragment, WALLET_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .commit();
    }
```

But, when I try to run the above code, I'm getting the following crash:

```
android.os.BadParcelableException: 
ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.wallet.shared.BuyFlowConfig
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2432)
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
at android.os.BaseBundle.putString(BaseBundle.java:430)
at android.content.Intent.putExtra(Intent.java:6394)
at com.test.BaseActivity.startActivityForResult(BaseActivity.java:122)
at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompatJB.java:31)
at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:163)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:948)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:1057)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:947)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:936)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzh.startActivityForResult(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzc$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
at lvg.a(:com.google.android.gms:728)
at com.google.android.gms.wallet.dynamite.fragment.b.a(:com.google.android.gms:551)
at aaee.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms:210)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The crash line is where I put `intent.putExtra` in my `BaseActivity`.

The weird part is that the app is crashing because it cannot unmarshall `com.google.android.gms.wallet.shared.BuyFlowConfig`. But it is failing because I am trying to put an extra in the same `intent` in my BaseActivity? I am very confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: any updates on this? I'm having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

The app's activity may be overriding startActivityForResult and attempting to modify the Intent that the Play Services API is firing. When you try to modify an intent, Android will try to unparcel the contents of the Bundle and then this error might happen due to the fact that this class doesn't exist in the ClientLibrary.